# IdentityServer 4 Entity Framework ConfigurationDbContext Client.AllowedScopes and Other Non-Clients Table Properties are Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identityserver4

I have a database initialization method in my .NET Core Startup.cs file that does Entity Framework database initializations on a MySql database and loads Clients, Identity Resources, and API Resources into the database from a configuration file (C# code). Inserting new clients works great as does updating client properties that are part of the `Clients` table (such as "description").  The issue I'm having is that the data that sits in other client-related tables, like `ClientScopes` or `ClientGrantTypes` is not coming back and populating in the `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.Client` object, so I can't compare my configuration against the database in code in order to add or remove any properties that have changed in the source controlled config file.

```
private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using IServiceScope serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
    ConfigurationDbContext context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
    foreach (IdentityServer4.Models.Client client in Config.GetClients())
    {
        Client contextClient = context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ClientId == client.ClientId);
        if (contextClient == null)
        {
            context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
        }
        else // for simplicity, leaving out any "else if" checks
        {
            Client entity = client.ToEntity();
            contextClient.Description = entity.Description;

            // Get client scopes that were removed from the client configuration and that are in the database
            // Exception (NullReferenceException) thrown because contextClient.AllowedScopes is NULL even though there are values in IdentityDb.ClientScopes, so the following two commands don't function as expected.
            var scopesToBeRemoveFromDb = contextClient.AllowedScopes.Where(p => !entity.AllowedScopes.Exists(x => x.Scope == p.Scope));
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there something I'm missing to ensure that the `context.Clients` call brings these additional tables' data back too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .Include() to load related data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data